# Can verbs of perception have an adjective in the objective complement position?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, complements

I know as below.

[verbs of perception  +  object  +  bare infinitive / present participle / past participle]

But I found this sentence.

> The note was heard loud.

Then can verbs of perception have an adjective in the objective complement position?

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148692/discussion-on-question-by-eunjin-park-can-verbs-of-perception-have-an-adjective); please do not continue the discussion here.